# Mapping "Reports" under Master Web Application having multiple products

Tags: user-behavior, information-architecture, user-expectation, users, information

There is web based application which has bad experience issues with reports and mapping. Currently application is mixture of 4 different products and they provide service to customer as per needs. Like Product A serves the need of monitoring, Product B do the firewall and etc. However, Customers subscribed based on service package rather than certain product( certain product help with different service requirement) so they have to navigate through different product option to download reports. Customers are experiencing issues with navigating reports and mapping it as per requirements. I am not sure what is the effective way of mapping the services and report to users like for Requirement 10.1 go here. Also some scnenarios auditor have issues locating them.

I also think part of is information architecture problem.

I am thinking of following solution and let me know if it fits the best per the problem statement.

1) Have a FAQ section inside the web application where they can find the service report mapping.
2) Build a unified report section: This is easy to say but difficult to build scenario as some time user subscribe to certain products and not just service for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Your proposal looks like an emergency solution: "My apartment is burning; How can I improve firemen efficiency?". Another view would be to prevent the apartment from burning in the first place...

Therefore, I would suggest a two steps approach:

1. First, a solution similar to yours, to help users as soon as possible. (You could lead some interviews or anything else to decide if the faq is the best solution, or something else better suiting user needs.
2. Then, you could take the time to redesign those 4 different products as a whole, as it seems that your users would be interested in a global seamless experience. This would require a stronger user-centered process, that would likely erase the troubles met in the current version. You could also think of how to degrade the whole consistent application for the users who would not purchase the 4 current parts of it.

Comment: There is resource limitation to look a this problem. Your 1. this has to be something without user interviews. 2. having combine 4 different products is something not possible at this point.

Comment: I understand your point. However, it's not so easy to propose an appropriate answer. The best approach would follow from a balance between your user research requirements and your available resources... This latter element is especially difficult to estimate by the UX StackExchange community...

Comment: There is always a resource limitation, especially when your apartment is on fire.  Perversely once you accept this you can start to think about how to use this to your advantage.  Yako's suggestions may be a good 'different way of looking at the problem', they are worth exploring.